# CoreSphere works in local but it doesn't work online

Tags: symfony

I have installed the CoreSphere ( console online ) after following this [tutorial](https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony2/utiliser-la-console-directement-depuis-le-navigateur) .. it works good in local but on line I have an error

```
FatalThrowableError in AppKernel.php line 36: 
Fatal error: Class 'CoreSphere\ConsoleBundle\CoreSphereConsoleBundle' not found
```

Comment: clear cache on production

Comment: yes i have clreared the cache but it still doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We must upload the vendor/composer because under way the installation the composer write in the vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php